# Explicit bijection between Jordan curves and real numbers

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

It is my understanding that the set of all Jordan curves and the set of real numbers are of the same cardinality.  So, it follows that there should exist a bijection between them.  Is there a known, explicit bijection between these two sets?  If so, what is it?

Comment: If someone could tell me why I was voted down, I would be very appreciative.

Comment: I deleted my answer. It is strange that everything on this page has a downvote...

Answer (score 3):

Recall that a Jordan curve is a continuous injection from the circle into $\Bbb R^2$. First let us see that indeed there are only $2^{\aleph_0}$ Jordan curves, then we can discuss explicitness.

The unit circle has the same cardinality as the real numbers (why?) and it is a separable space, that is to say that it has a dense countable subset. Recall that a continuous function is uniquely extended from the values it takes on a dense subset. So we can fix $Q$ to be a countable dense subset and two Jordan curves which take the same values when restricted to that set will have to be equal.

It follows, if so, that the collection of *all* continuous functions from $S^1$ to $\mathbb R^2$ has the cardinality of at most $2^{\aleph_0}$, as demonstrated in the following argument, $$\left|(\Bbb R^2)^Q\right|=|\mathbb R^2|^{|Q|}=(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}=|\mathbb R|.$$

So the collection of Jordan curves cannot have *more* than $2^{\aleph_0}$ elements; but it also cannot have less. Simply note that if $r\in\mathbb R$ is a positive number then scaling the unit circle to the circle of radius $r$ is a Jordan curve. Therefore we have $$|\mathbb R|\leq|\cal J|\leq|\mathbb R|.$$
(Where $\cal J$ is the set of all Jordan curves.)

By the Cantor-Bernstein theorem it follows that $|\cal J|=|\Bbb R|$.

But wait a minute, we didn't really write any explicit bijection! Am I just pulling your legs with some mathematical nonsense? Well, no. I'm not actually. The Cantor-Bernstein theorem allows us to generate an explicit bijection from given injections. It is hardly ever a pretty bijection, though. When we think about "explicit functions" we often think in terms of "$x\mapsto x^2+e^{\pi x}$ or something like that, some nice closed term formula. But the truth is that the majority of functions cannot be written like that, or even piece-wise like that.

If one is so inclined then all it is possible to work from the equalities and inequalities the various injections needed and to use the Cantor-Bernstein theorem to write out an explicit bijection, but this function will not be very pretty.

Comment: Does the downvote signifies a particular uniformity with the rest of the posts on this page being downvoted?